# Switching elm version with homebrew - permissions issue

Tags: homebrew, elm

I am trying to switch versions of elm, as installed by homebrew.

```
elm --version
0.18.0

brew switch elm 0.16.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.16.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.18.0
7 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.16.0/
brew prune
brew link elm

elm --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/elm: Permission denied
```

File permissions of the folders containing 0.16.0 and 0.17.0:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  5 my.name admin   170B 10 Feb 09:53 0.16.0/
drwxr-xr-x   7 my.name  admin   238B 10 Feb 09:52 0.18.0/
```

If I switch back to 0.18.0, everything works correctly:

```
brew switch elm 0.18.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.16.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.18.0
6 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.18.0
brew prune
brew link elm
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/elm/0.18.0
To relink: brew unlink elm && brew link elm
elm --version
0.18.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `npm` is best for installing `elm`.

`brew uninstall elm`

`npm install elm@0.16.0`

Done

Answer (score 2):

There is also a tool like `nvm` (node version manager) for switching `elm` versions. Here https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-use you can read more info about it.

You can easily install it with

`npm install -g elm-use`

Then you can do `elm-use 0.17` or whatever version you want to use